# How to add copy to clipboard button in android?

Tags: android, clipboardmanager

I want to add a button that will copy the text from non-editable textview inside a cardview. Can I use clipboard manager for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**try this**
**define variables**

```
private ClipboardManager myClipboard;
private ClipData myClip;
```

**on button click listener**

```
//to copy data to clip board
    copy_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            myClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            String text;
            text = edidata.getText().toString();

            myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", text);
            myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text Copied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

**i hope this work in your case**

Answer (score 1):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11) {
android.content.ClipboardManager c = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
  c.setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText("sinaweibo", buildShareCopyContent()));

} else {
  android.text.ClipboardManager c = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
c.setText(activitioncode.getText());
}
```